# Is there a .def file equivalent on Linux for controlling exported function names in a shared library?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I am building a shared library on Ubuntu 9.10. I want to export only a subset of my functions from the library. On the Windows platform, this would be done using a module definition (`.def`) file which would contain a list of the external and internal names of the functions exported from the library.

I have the following questions:

1. How can I restrict the exported functions of a shared library to those I want (i.e. a .def file equivalent)
2. Using .def files as an example, you can give a function an external name that is different from its internal name (useful for prevent name collisions and also redecorating mangled names etc)
3. On windows I can use the EXPORT command (IIRC) to check the list of exported functions and addresses, what is the equivalent way to do this on Linux?

Answer (score 12):

The most common way to only make certain symbols visible in a shared object on linux is to pass the `-fvisibility=hidden` to gcc and then decorate the symbols that you want to be visible with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`.

If your looking for an export file like solution you might want to look at the linker option `--retain-symbols-file=FILENAME` which may do what you are looking for.

I don't know an easy way of exporting a function with a different name from its function name, but it is probably possible with an elf editor.  **Edit:** I think you can use a linker script (have a look at the man page for ld) to assign values to symbols in the link step, hence giving an alternative name to a given function. Note, I haven't ever actually tried this.

To view the visible symbols in a shared object you can use the `readelf` command. `readelf -Ds` if I remember correctly.

Comment: You don't actually need to decorate them with visibility set to default, as that's the default...

Comment: @Fredrik Ullner: I don't understand your point. If you use `-fvisibility=hidden` then have to re-set the visibility to default of those symbols that you don't want hidden otherwise no symbols would be visible.

Comment: "then decorate the symbols that you want to be visible with __attribute__((visibility("default")))." You don't need to do that, since that is the default.

Comment: @Fredrik Ullner: Yes, it's the default, but not when you use `-fvisibility=hidden` when hidden becomes the default. You then have to (somehow) change the visibility of the symbols that you want to be externally visible back from hidden which you can do with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` .  Try it: `echo 'void f() {}' | gcc -xc -c -fvisibility=hidden -o a.o - && readelf -s a.o` shows that the visiblity of `f` is hidden, unlike here: `echo 'void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) f() {}' | gcc -xc -c -fvisibility=hidden -o a.o` .

Answer (score 8):

> How can I restrict the exported functions of a shared library to those I want (i.e. a .def file equivalent)

Perhaps you're looking for [GNU Export Maps](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1372) or [Symbol Versioning](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=33)

`g++ -shared spaceship.cpp -o libspaceship.so.1 
-Wl,-soname=libspaceship.so.1 -Wl,
--version-script=spaceship.expmap`

Comment: perhaps, the map file helps us with defining what symbols to export, however, unlike the def file in windows, on linux, the linker does not error out if it sees a function in map file that is not defined.  Is there any way I can error out if the function is not found similar to windows?

Answer (score 4):

gcc also supports the VC syntax of __declspec(dllexport). See [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Comment: But only when compiling for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the strip command with this way:

```
strip --keep-symbol=symbol_to_export1 --keep-symbol=symbol_to_export2 ... \
     libtotrip.so -o libout.so
```