# translate LIBTOOL's export-symbol to GCC

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, shared-libraries, autotools

is there something similar to Libtool's `-export-symbols-regex` in GCC?
As far as I understand, Libtool generates Makefiles for different toolchains. Hence, Libtool's `-export-symbols-regex` must somehow be translated to GCC flags etc, right?

I'm building a shared library and remove unused symbols with -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections. Now, I want to tell GCC which functions to keep.

This is what I suspect Libtool does with `-export-symbols-regex 'foo'`. But how to achieve this with a pure Makefile calling GCC directly?

Comment: You are mistaken in the assumption that libtool generates makefiles,
or that the `-export-symbol-regex` generates commandline options for
GCC. The option works by generating a custom linker script for the
linker, a task you'd much better leave to `libtool`. There's
no reason why you can't use `libtool` in your own makefile, per
[the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Using-libtool).

Comment: It's also unlikely that you *need* to use libtool to build a shared
library just as you want it, unless your build needs to be multi-platform.
I suggest you scrap this question and post one that
minimally shows the feature(s) you want your shared library to
have, but do not know how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand, Libtool generates Makefiles for different toolchains.

No, automake's job is to generate Makefiles.  libtool's job is dealing with the peculiarities of building shared libraries across various platforms.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839504/is-there-a-def-file-equivalent-on-linux-for-controlling-exported-function-names) has some different methods that you can try with GCC.  libtool is probably using the export map technique.